# Error date-string format to Date type in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Input:
var date = ee.Date.parse('YYYYMMDD','20221101');
print(date)

Output:
Date (2022-01-01 00:00:00)

Answer (score 0):

`var date = ee.Date.parse('yyyyMMdd','20220901');`

[pattern describe](https://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).